# Adding static Excel to automatically refreshing Power BI report

Tags: powerbi

I have an existing PowerBI report that imports data from an SQL Server analytics services database. This is working fine and I can schedule automatic refreshes using the Gateway provided by my organization.

I would now like to add some additional, but rarely changing data, that I only have in a local Excel file. When I do add this data, the report stops refreshing automatically and complains, that it has no gateway to refresh this Excel file.

What I would like is that Power BI is refreshing the data of the SQL Server analytics services database, but just keeps the existing Excel file without updating it. - I will upload an updated version of the PowerBI report if I need to change the data in the Excel file.

Is that possible? I couldn't find out how. I was trying to upload the Excel file to a different dataset to the Power BI service and reference this dataset in my report. Just to find out, that I cannot access a different Power BI dataset and SQL server analysis services database from the same report.

Comment: A quick hack could be to upload the excel file to share point or Excel online and use that as the data source.

Comment: @Dev Good idea as a work around. Still somehow it feels as work around and that there should be a different solution as well

Answer (score 0):

Three things I can think of

1. Upload the file to onedrive/sharepoint so that it's accessible online (per Dev's answer)
2. If the data is simple enough, you can add the data directly into PowerBI itself and skip the Excel file entirely.

[image: UI]

3. You can disable the Excel file refresh so that PBI does not try and refresh(and thus access) the local Excel file. (Not sure if this will work)

[image: UI]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I came across.  Yes, you can just use Enter Data to add a table, but you can only build something with less than 3000 cells, so you'd have to merge several tables if something was larger than that.

Turning off the report refresh in the suggestion above (#3) still requires a gateway, unfortunately.

I just created a dataflow and plopped the data from my csv there.  You'll have to create a connection and refresh it, but you don't need to schedule a refresh there, so no need to create a gateway.

Then just link the dataflow as a source to your .pbix file and setup your gateway to point at the dataflow.